# Android: Write float[] audio buffer to PCM WAV file

Tags: android, audio, wav, pcm

I have a `float[]` array containing an audio buffer that I've created programmatically and I want to write it to a PCM WAV file.

I was hoping [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) would include an [Audio Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) of something like "Memory Buffer", but alas its options are limited to hardware sources.

I also wondered if [AudioTrack.write(float[], int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#write(float[],%20int,%20int,%20int)) might do this, but I couldn't see if "audio sink" could be a physical file. The audio sink seems to be synonymous with speaker output.

I could just flush the raw buffer to disk as others seems to have tried, but it wouldn't take care of the WAV header.

`Audio Buffer -> WAV file` seems like a pretty standard use case to me. Does Android not facilitate this at all? If not, I'd have to build a WAV file with its header manually.